# Newbie to Selenium E2E with React

Tags: reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, e2e-testing

I created a boilerplate React project, packages.json has the usual suspects:

- prestart
- start
- list
- test
- etc.

I am using Selenium for my E2E framework. I have the following test:

```
it('should launch a browser', () => {

    const By = webDriver.By;
    let driver = new webDriver.Builder()
      .forBrowser('chrome')
      .build();

    // verify Continue button exist on page
    driver.navigate().to('http://localhost:3000').then(() => driver.findElement(By.id('submitButton')).getAttribute('value'))
      .then(buttonValue => expect(buttonValue).toEqual('Continue'));

  });
```

If I do `npm start`, my site launches and my E2E launches an additional Chrome browser and navigate to my running site: `localhost:3000`. The test succeeds.

My question is, how do I run my E2E separately, without the need to my site side by side using `npm start`.

I am newbie to React and Selenium, in case I am missing a lot of information on this post, I apologize in advance.

Comment: Hey there Pacman! I think I might have a solution for you, but you need to update your question with the **package.json** content as this `packages.json has the usual suspects: prestart start list test etc...` won't cut it. Also, apart from Mocha, are you using any other testing framework to supply your Selenium JS-bindings?

Comment: Well, your site has to run somewhere. If it doesn't run on localhost, it must run somewhere else, otherwise there is nothing to test.

Comment: Pacman, have you read my answer, or comment suggestion? Still want to debug this issue? Your bounty is already in the grace period, so if you don't take an action, it will be lost.

Comment: Well, I guess you just didn't care about the question/bounty getting a solution...

Answer (score 6):

Well, since you didn't find the time to update the question information with the NPM `"scripts"` object, then I'll try to give it a shot in the dark.

First of all, due to your wording, I can interpret your question two ways:

- **a.)** you want to run your **E2E tests** *separately*, w/o your server running (which is started via `npm start`);
- **b.)** you want to run your **E2E tests** via `npm start`, without triggering your server from starting;

---

**a.)** If you want to run your scripts separately, seeing as you are using **Mocha**, then you can trigger them via: `./node_modules/.bin/mocha <pathToTests>/<testFile>`.

Now, since you stated in your question that you're using `npm test` script, then that should be the best switch to bind your **E2E tests** execution to:

**package.json** (Scripts object):

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec <pathToTests>/<testFile>",
    "start": "node <yourServerName>.js"
},
```

Please note that `mocha <pathToTests>/<testFile>` is equivalent to `./node_modules/.bin/mocha <pathToTests>/<testFile>`, because **NPM** looks for binaries inside `node_modules/.bin` and when Mocha was installed, it installed it into this directory.

> **Note:** Many packages have a `bin`, or `.bin` section, declaring scripts that can be called from NPM similar to Mocha. If you want to find out what other binaries you can run that way, just issue a `ls node_modules/.bin`.

---

**b.)** In this care, I think your issue might be due to NPM defaulting some script values based on package contents. Specifically, if you have a `server.js` file in the root of your package, then npm will default the start command to `server.js`.

So if you're starting your **E2E tests** via `npm start`, having this (`"start": "mocha <pathToTests>/<testFile>"`) in your **package.json** and there is a **server.js** file in the root of your package, then npm will default the start command to `node server.js`.

In which case, you could either move your server script to another place in the project, or change the switch you're using to trigger the **E2E tests** (`see section b.)`).

Hope this solves your problem and if not, looking forward for that `package.json` `"scripts"` object so we can really see what's up. :)

Cheers!